# How to map an array for the multi pages dynamically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I'm not sure if someone has answered this question here, but I'm facing some difficulty to find answer for this question.

This is an example of my array:

```
{
   task_1: [.....],[.....],
   task_2: [.....],[.....],
   task_3: [.....],[.....]
}
```

each of this tasks has their items that render on different page, similar to quiz apps each task should have their separate page to be rendered, so my question is that is there any way to map those tasks dynamically  instead of making duplicate pages for each of these tasks?

instead of this:

```
{task_1.map(items=>{
.....
})

-> click to next page

{task_2.map(items=>{
.....
})
```

i want this:

```
{dynamic.map(items=>{
.....
})
-> click to next page
```

note: this is an React Native app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would just have to use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to retrieve the tasks as a separate array and map over those.

Then, just nest what you currently have inside of the result. Like so:

```
<div> 
    {/* Iterate over all of the tasks (object keys) */}
    { Object.keys(tasks).map(taskName => (
        <div key={taskName}>
            <!-- Essentially the same as task_1, task_2, etc... -->
            { tasks[taskName].map( items => ( ... )) }
            <a href="#">Click to next page...</a>
        </div>
    )) }
</div>
```

Technically, you could use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) instead of `Object.keys()` - but I tend to gravitate towards the latter since it gives me the option of using the object property as the `key` prop value.

Comment: Thank you Grover, you got it right, but Once we click on next button it should fire next task, how it should be?